# Why can't the diene in a diels-alder also be a dienophile

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reactivity

why can't the diene react with itself like this[image]

Comment: it does it just has a really low yield

Comment: ... because it's a bad dienophile

Answer (score 5):

It can and does given the right diene. The classic case is [cyclopentadiene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopentadiene):

> At room temperature, this cyclic diene dimerizes over the course of hours to give dicyclopentadiene via a Diels–Alder reaction. This dimer can be restored by heating to give the monomer.

Note the thermoreversibility of the reaction in this case, which opens up a relatively easy route to aromatic cyclopentadienide-ion rings.

Comment: Freshly distilled cyclopentadiene cracked from the dimer is neutral, and its dimer/product of the Diels-Alder reaction is uncharged, too.  Neither cyclopentadiene, nor dicyclopentadiene feature a planar cyclic array of $(2n + 2)$ $\pi$ electrons to qualify as aromatic. The large gain of stability if cyclopentadiene is deprotonated because the resulting anion/base then equally is an aromatic aromatic structure is separate, independent of cyclopentadiene's ability to dimerize quickly at room temperature.